# nunit-console hangs in remote powershell session after finishing test run

Tags: powershell, nunit, powershell-remoting, nunit-console

I'm running NUnit tests using the following PS line:

```
& 'D:\tools\nunit-console.exe' D:\MyApplication.Specs.dll /run=MyApplication.MyTest /framework=net-4.5 /nothread
```

This line is working fine.
After that I'm running the same test in remote session on the same PC with following line:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyHost -ScriptBlock { & 'D:\tools\nunit-console.exe' D:\MyApplication.Specs.dll /run=MyApplication.MyTest /framework=net-4.5 /nothread } -credential MyUser
```

After the test execution is finished nunit-console hangs with following output:

```
NUnit-Console version 2.6.3.13283
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.5477 ( Net 3.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-4.5
Selected test(s): MyApplication.MyTest
.
Tests run: 1, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 6.96245315227513 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I have noticed nunit-agent process in task manager. If I kill this process test execution is finished successfully.

Comment: I suspect you have the answer to your own question now, right? :) If that's the case, it would be great if you post it here for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests are running in separate manually created ASP.NET application domain via Remoting. The solution is to unload this app domain when all tests are passed. Global NUnit TearDown method is useful in this case :)